# Showing one set is a subset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, discrete-mathematics

Let's say you have sets $A,\, B,$ and $C.$

How would you show that $[(A-B) - C]\subseteq (A-C)$ using a venn diagram or logical translations?

How can this even be done when you don't know the members of $A,\, B,$ or $C$?

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.google.com/#q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com+%22element+chasing%22) for some examples. I also recommend you look at the book [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-Structured-Daniel-Velleman/dp/0521675995), by [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Comment: If $x \in [(A-B)-C]$ that means $x$ is in $A$, but in neither $B$ nor $C$. How would you characterize an element of $(A-C)$ similarily?

Comment: @Arthur x is in A, but not in C. How can I combine the two to conclude they're subsets of each other?

Comment: @Bob They aren't subsets of each other.

Comment: By the way, if two sets _are_ subsets of each other, then they are equal.

Comment: I'm trying to show that [(A-B)-C] is a subset of (A-C) using a logical equivalence. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Bob: but the two sets are not equal (not equivalent). What IS TRUE is that $\,(A - B) - C\,$ is a *subset of* $\,A - C,\,$ which simply means that all of $\,(A-B) - C\,$ is "contained within" $A - C$. By definition of "subset", that means every element of $\,(A - B) - C\,$ is necessarily also an element of $\,A - C\,$ but not necessarily the other way around. Two sets $X, Y$ are equal if and only if $X\subseteq Y$ AND $Y\subseteq X$. Here we have only one containment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to use logical translations, implicitly (no need for logic symbols though - words work fine), in the sense that you need to use the *definition of set-minus* where $\;x \in X - Y\;$ *means* that $\;x \in X\;$ **AND** $\,x \notin Y.$

Showing that set-membership in $\,X\,$ *implies* set-membership in $\,Y,\,$ proves that $\,X\subseteq Y$. Logically, this is establishing that $\,x \in [(A - B) - C] \implies x \in (A - C).$

In this case, start by assuming $\,x \in (A - B) - C,\,$ and then unpack what this means using the *definition* of set-minus. Using this you can argue that it must follow that $\,x \in A-C.\,$ This is equivalent to proving that $\,(A-B) -C \subseteq A - C$.

Comment: Ah, so this would 'show' that they are subsets of each other?

Comment: I suppose I am confusing the word 'show' with 'prove'.

Comment: See the edited answer, Bob.

Comment: @Bob To clarify, this only proves that $(A-B)-C\subseteq A-C$. It doesn't prove that they are subsets of each other, it just proves one is a subset of the other.

Comment: Is it possible to write out an equivalence to x ∈ (A-B) - C ---> x ∈ (A-C)?

It doesn't make any sense that you can just write that out, without proving (A-B) - C is a subset of A-C

Comment: @Bob What my answer is saying is that we can express $[(A - B) - C] \subseteq (A - C)$ as the logically equivalent statement $\,x \in [(A-B)-C] \rightarrow x \in (A-C).\,$ So to prove $\,[(A - B) - C] \subseteq (A - C),\,$ we need to prove $\,x \in [(A-B)-C] \rightarrow x \in (A-C).\,$ To prove this, we start by assuming $\,x \in [(A - B) - C]$, and show that this implies $(\rightarrow)\,$ that $\,x \in (A-C).\,$ That's a very straightforward task, but once you've done that, you've proven the equivalent statement $\,[(A - B) - C] \subseteq [A - C]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've figured it out with your help.

Comment: You're welcome, @Bob! I knew you could do it!

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in(A-B)-C$. By the definition of set difference we know that $x\in A-B$ and $x\notin C$. Since $x\in A-B$ we know that $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. Thus we have $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$ which implies that $x\in A-C$ and we can conclude that $(A-B)-C\subseteq A-C$.

Comment: How do we know this about $x$?  What is $x$?

Comment: amWhy posted the first step for Bob by letting x be an element of (A-B)-C. I was just letting Bob know what needs to follow by using the definition of set difference.

Comment: Oh, I see.  But I think if you're going to post this as an answer rather than a comment on amWhy's answer, then it should be self-contained.

Comment: I understand. Is my edit acceptable?

Comment: Yep, looks good now.

Comment: I'm new to this site. I'm learning slowly. Any tips are greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)